# Pushing package to Octopus Deploy using powershell script

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy

I am new to Powershell and I am writing a script to push a package to Octopus Deploy.

#Function to push packages to Octopus Deploy

```
function Push-Package {
param(
    $OctopusUri,
    $ApiKey,
    $Package
)
try{
  Write-Host "Pushing $($Package.Fullname) to Octopus"
  .\Octo.exe 'push' --package $Package.Fullname --server $OctopusUri --apiKey $ApiKey --logLevel 'verbose'
  Write-Host "Pushing $($Package.Fullname) to Octopus - Success"
}
catch{
   Write-Host "PUSH PACKAGE Exception--------- $_"
}
}

$OctopusUri = "https://MyTestOctopus.local"
$ApiKey = "API-3Z3NRPNLUTS6ULA2KDALWG6A3HA"
$PackageFolder = "c:\temp\OctoTest"

Push-Package "https://MyTestOctopus.local" "API-3Z3NRPNLUTS6ULA2KDALWG6A3HA" "C:\temp\OctoTest\MyTestPackage.1.1.0.zip"
```

I am getting an error:

PUSH PACKAGE Exception--------- The term '.\Octo.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

I am not sure what I am doing wrong above. Any help would be great.

Comment: The Octo.exe was porbably not found at the location. Either cd to the directory where the Octo.exe is residing OR provide the full path of the exe.

Comment: I have downloaded octo.exe and pointed to the location of the file. Still getting an error: The term 'octo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet. Do I have to install octo.exe or just point to the location??

Comment: You can try this:
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath "FULL PATH TO YOUR OCTO EXE" -ArgumentList 'push',"--package $( $Package.Fullname )","--server $OctopusUri", "--apiKey $ApiKey", "--logLevel 'verbose'"

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks alot.